# Does garbage collector purge global variable property in NodeJs?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, garbage-collection

I am assigning a mongoose db connection to the global object as `global.mongoose_instance` which is then used int the controller module. This seems to be working fine so far in development and staging environment, but in production the global.mongoose_instance is `undefined` when I use it in the controller. The only reason I can think of is that the GC is purging this property. Is it plausible and how can I prevent it?

Comment: Seems like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you want to solve the production issue (X) ask about the production issue, rather than whether or not it's related to GC (Y).

Comment: Most garbage collection systems I'm aware of eliminate garbage when they can prove that the garbage objects are no longer reachable. They thus have no need/design to clear any variables because those variables themselves must not have been reachable. If you can reach the variable, it could reach the object, and so the object wouldn't have been considered garbage.